# Alert user when stealed an HTML template via Jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have uploaded an HTML template to themeforest, but i found some of the websites is giving the full source code for free. As it is HTML, anycone can easily copy it. Instead of obfuscating, Is there any method in Jquery to alert the user if they hosted my template on other website (track IP) with out purchasing ? 
Meaasge like "You are stealed my template".

It is good, if i got an email about the IP address (via jquery or php). Then i can also alert the Stealer. Also the code should be hidden, that they cannot remove it.

So, HTML hosted on my website eg:120.7.7.7 - No Alerts.

Someone copy that HTML and uploading to other website eg:112.215.11.11 - Alert to Stealer like "You stealed my template", Also i got an email regarding that steal.

Comment: Your concern is about rips??? content type css... use PHP, set header to css / js ... check for user_agent... or, alternatively, give a button to click on... once that button is clicked, start a session and if session exists, show the website... httrack does not store session cookies... cool?

Comment: @KarmicDice im new to PHP, can you explain what to to, or give me a link for tutorial.

Comment: It's easy enough to code it to alert you if it's not used on a particular website; the problem is telling the code which sites are legitimate. Unless Themeforest makes it possible for you to customize the files for each purchaser, there's no good way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to secure your client side source code for 100%. You can make it harder to read for people though.

The template is HTML, CSS and JS is rendered by the client browser. So that person can easily check the source code and copy paste it to do whatever they like with it.

You can obfuscate the HTML, example: http://www.ioncube.com/html_encoder.php

But you can't force buyers of your template to do that.

So in short: No, you can't

Comment: That product is not a very serious or maintained one anymore. Anyone with the Firefox plugin Firebug can get access to HTML straightaway. So to support Sven's answer in short, no.

Comment: Firebug's not even necessary - Firefox ships with developer tools that display the "encoded" site right away.

Comment: Didn't checked the status of the project. It's more an direction to point out. The debug tools are getting better and better so it's an waste of time to try to decode the source code. People will find an way to read it if they really want to.

Comment: Yep, just use chrome and press F12 and you will see the decoded web page.

Answer (score 1):

No. Anyone who copies the page could simply remove the method.

Comment: We can hide it in jquery library or the JS file they needed. We can also obfuscate jquery

Comment: also if we got email of server IP, Fist time, then we can take action

Comment: Your question said that it was HTML. If it is just HTML there there is no JS file needed. But even if there is obfuscating just adds a couple of minutes to the time taken to remove the unwanted part.

Comment: my file has JS too.. Like a normal website i mean. html, css, images and js

Answer (score 1):

The truth is it's almost impossible to restrict access to client side assets.

Any methods that do restrict access will only do so for inexperienced users. Anyone who is determined will be able to get access to all your HTML, CSS and Javascript.

You can minify CSS and Javascript, and with Javascript in particular, arrange the code so that it is difficult to understand. However JavaScript can always be reversed, and no matter what any obfuscator's method is, you will able to run through the obfuscated code and study it in any modern browser. Except if the obfuscator would also package code meant to make your life harder to prevent the use of debug tools, but it would just be eventually circumvented and rendered useless as well.

If you really need secrecy for your code, then don't use JavaScript and rely on other technologies. If you approach the problem the other way around, and you already built the new coolest JS-based web-app and want it to be hidden: give it up.

So really, the answer to your question is unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I already said something like this on SO once: if you don't want the client to have some code **don't give it to him!** It's that simple. If you give code to your clients most are able to and some will access and 'steal' that code.
If you need to give a preview of a template take a screenshot of it and display that (as an image) instead.